# Using NULL to replace values in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When is the best case to use NULL, 0, or FLOAT64 in Google BigQuery?

For example, replacing default values of temperatures, precipitation and wind speed (from a previous activity) as

```
IF(
        temp=9999.9,
        NULL,
        temp) AS temperature,
```

or

```
IF(
       prcp=99.99,
       0,
       prcp) AS precipitation
```

or

```
IF(
        wdsp="999.9",
        NULL,
        CAST(wdsp AS Float64)) AS wind_speed,
```

I'm new to SQL and I find writing these query examples long, time-consuming, and difficult to memorize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a short way to set a value to `null` by using the function `nullif`.

```
with tbl as (Select 999.9 as wdsp, 99.99  as prcp union all select 1,1)


Select *,
  if(prcp between 0 and 99, prcp, 0) as precipitation,
  nullif(cast(wdsp as float64),999.9) AS wind_speed
from tbl
```

The cast to float should not be needed here, because `wdsp` is already a decimal value, right?

The difference between `null` and `0.0` is that in aggegation function such as `avg` the `null` entries are ignored.

```
with tbl as (Select 9 as x union all select 5 )


Select avg(x),
avg(nullif(x,5)),
avg(if(x=5,0,x)),

from tbl
```

The mean of 9 and 5 is (9+5)/2=14/2=7. If we set the 5 to `null`, the only remaining number is the 9 and the result is 9. If we set the 5 to 0, the result is (9+0)/2=4.5